# Google Play Games api quota and isConnected()

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

Google play games apparently has api quotas in my app I call the function `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()` in a loop. I wanted to be sure that this function doesn't rack up my api quota. I could just use booleans, but I'd prefer the code be clean as possible. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no network traffic when calling isConnected, so it should not affect your quota.  The pattern of calling mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() is very common and I agree - its cleaner.

Comment: Thanks I guess I'll go with this.

Comment: @NJGUY, I agree with ClaytonWilkinson, it's unlikely.  Why not open the API Developer Console and track it yourself (APIs, Google Play Games Services, Usage).